# getting latest data with high replication datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

In the GAE [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/hr/overview.html), it states:

> Remember, if you do a get(), put(), or a transaction, you will always see the most recently written data.

I understand that `db.get(key)` always returns the most recently written data, but what about other gets?  If I have an entity `Voters` and do this:

```
voter = Voters.order("email").get()
```

will I always see the most recently written data?

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but it would be good if the docs were more explicit.

Comment: It's deceptive, but what you're doing there is not a 'get', but a query. `get` is just a convenience method that returns the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "queries that require strongly consistent results must contain an
>   ancestor filter, which restricts the results to a single entity group.
>   Queries that span multiple entity groups are **not guaranteed** to
>   return up-to-date results. See the Using the High Replication
>   Datastore for more information about using ancestor queries in this
>   context."

[Source](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/hr/#Comparing_the_Data_Storage_Options)